# Problem in saving the image saving from url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cheerio

I'm trying to **scrape** data from website while **scraping** it i'm getting error like file "An error ocured while loading image" while opening image from my server directory.image is stored with extension but the image is not opening properly

```
var request = require('request');  
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
 
const fs = require("fs");
 

function hello (){
    url = '';
    request(url, function(error, response, html){


        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
             var img = $('img.control-label');
             var img_url = $('img.control-label').attr('src')
             console.log(img);
             console.log(url+img_url);
            
            request({url: url+img_url, headers: {Cookie: response.headers,encoding:null  }}, function(error1, response1, body){
                if(!error){ 
                    path1 = './image/new.jpeg';
                    data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
                    console.log(data); 
                    fs.writeFile(path1, body, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err){
                      });

                }
            })
        }
    })
}
hello();
```

below is the result of the console log of data before writing the file

```
data:text/html;base64,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
    (node:21396) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

**EDIT 1:**

after some tries I've come to this that image actually converted to some diffrent format when to write  following are the code 1 is working with my hard coded encoded uri but when i convert same code with URL it's giving the unusual errors

```
//console.log(data);  not wrking
                    binaryData1  =   "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+body.toString();
                    base64Data1  =   binaryData1.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ""); 
                    binaryData1  =   new Buffer(base64Data1, 'base64').toString('binary');
                    console.log(body)
                   
                    //working
                     binaryData  =   "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUTExMVFhUXGBcYFxcYGBgXGBgXGhcXFxcaFxcYHSggGholHxcYITEhJSkrLi4uHR8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKBQUFDgUFDisZExkrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrK//AABEIAQwAvAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQIDBgcBAP/EADoQAAEDAgUCAwYGAQQBBQAAAAEAAhEDIQQFEjFBUWEicYEGEzKRodEUQlKxwfAjBzPh8WIVQ4KSsv/EABQBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwBK+kqXUU0NNVmkgVuoqDaEkBNDRXtCj42lBfg/ZR1Rs6gD0IP7ypu9iq/BYfUj+FsMtxcNu0IqtmrWj4T8wg55U9lsQPyT5EKh2QVh/wC0/wCU/sugjO6fLXD0+yIp5zQ/VHmCP3CDl1TLnjdpHmCFUcKuw0sVRds9h9Ql+ZYOk8wQ2PRByz8OVD3JXW8L7M0HN8VNvy/lQr+xWGOzSPJx/koOTgHqvveOXSq3sFSOz3j5H+Eur+wTvy1B6t+xQYcViETRqSnz/YnETbSR5kKp/spimXNOe4c0/wAoEdUlU+8KYV6JaYcII3CHLUA5fZI8ebp7WFln8Z8SAQhRIU3KBKCBC8XpXkoOqwvCxXNavQ1AP7tVVWXTANVLWS9AZgA9osUS2TuiqFMBqqG6C04KUvxeH08J7QqCEJmIBCBZQc3mE2wlJpCzjqoBTrB4xoAQNW13M2cY8z9EUcxdFn/sk7sU07FC4it0QMaueVQbFpHcfYhW08+dHiYPQx91nHTK9dUd6INZhs9by0j5FFVs3pFvI8wf4WKw73SisRioagSe1WLY6pLR5lZ41gjs1dJSmpTKD7EVJCR4lplM6jShns7IFrmlQdKYuYFW6kEC8rxGOoqBoIOq6VPSvmhThBFeYJkvlWO2S8YvQ6UGnqtGnuhhSJQlHMdUQn2BpSJKBbLgVVipIKfnChD4nCiEHOc2rPDrDlQpZhVA+ErVYnLGuPqpDKWoMwzOHDcH5KYzed0+qZKDwhquRDogEp5oJiU1w1TUJSp2ThpnZM8M0NG6A1jI3QmYVrQqMZmQDSCJMFIG5tqmRHZBLFCShHtU6uIvZeapCAaoxDvporUJUHNQAVKKpcxHuCpc0IAnBQRLqarLEHTGhWBQYFMIPqmyzmYk6loq5skNZsuQX5POoLoGXt8KxGUU/EFvMEPCEFxCAzCrATGEuzClIQJDUkoqmVClhjKMbhzwgrY8EwvMSWtFyAk+KzRrXP4NMeInaCbLBZr7W1n1iGPls6YgQeCP4QaLN/aLQSYaI2Lj8R/8QL+pIWWzHOn1R8enmGiPmboHF4kHc33P/aW4rEAfbp590Del7QOFiZOwJjV68Kp+Zk3CUYY6t/78wrvdTsf4QHjHSb3V9DNI32SV8jdS1WkeoQaeljGOPEq/3gNlkW14TnLcZqME8IGTgqnBEOVZagGe1UlqJcFW5B0NqsCqaVYghiDZLG0CbwYTOoJIHdaDAZSS2YQZfCHQZMp5Rz5ogSh/aHCaGExwuXfjCa0AndB2uhmjTypVsW0rL5Fhy5oMlF4qi5uxKBzTrNRge2FmqGEquEjdG0MBiOyDFf6gYMl5q0z4RZ7dj5kdJJ+a55Uo6IM3InyXYPabCODTqaHRM79L7cbLluaQCBv1KBIKt5THIvZ+rineEEM5cRb06pjkGQurObUcz/CXsbPUl7WugcxcLtWHy9lMQ1oA4gIOPZv7KOwwDhfqUhrPAPdd3zXAtqMc1wkELiHtHlrqNVzTMTY9kAr6gInpKhTduCq6WHe6wBMr59EgXKD56qZULTIXpb1XiDS5XmQcA078d0yhY3B1IeJWpbioAJ2O3XtZBa5qrhXm6rhBsW4odVY3Gt6rGsxjj1RFB7iQg2WEqAvb5roOAA0hcxyxhJHJW9y4PDQgC9tyBQf5FcYyLLTWqz3/AGXT/byq80iOqxXsQ8Sezig6hkOWNY0W4VuY4ZvRSw+YBrdkpxub6ngINBgqIDQi2vb2SUY0abJWMcZN0HvtXiNPjLQabZJE9oBMcSAfksv7L+xnvKfv8QA5p/2qZA2n43/qngevRap+HFbciADIP5hvp9VTXzxxsxukbW4A47IFODySpQqve+o0UdWsU9zrGxAHw9/IJ1l+f0a0ta4am2I2KS5qHGm5xJMCfNZ5+XjRTxFF+l7hx+ofE1w6jZBv8Tieiwvtm5huWibozCZ2ajSHDS9phwWU9rsYS4DsgQ4is7aYHZBo33fhaev3VFRsfQoBwvnNVhAVVRyCJRNOvtMkCPvH0QXKJY7gDgyg1eGqBwEbQrCEtwOMaGAeneUypEEAoPsOwJthKeyT0Kl01wVS6DYezFCX3XRqWHAaudezNbS663oxg07oMh7dkBsLMf6eZcH6njYuP7q//UXHk+EHqmP+nrmsptag2ZyoRtws3isq/wAgjqtn+KbBulAcHVEFQyiWpbWyMg2K2tMCEuzxsUi5v5bnyvP7z6IOfZ5jjRcGtNmktd31R4vKRHYFWfhHPjS7wm58ugXmdYZtW/z8l5lrnU2BszFpQN62CDqelc/xPs5XpvdpJLCdRB69luG5lCqxOZgjhBh20nNeXXuLjuFnc+8T4WxzrHsAJWAx+ILnzwgjiajYa1kwAd+bmf4QtSpIH1RDcPqFkPWoubughqmypcVYHqDm/NB4wqykSOEWaDGsF5cd+g7dyqtEcoGWCpsjYuPQfytE1tkpyXARFQuJJG3H/abAoFdF6b5Y+6RUnJxlW6DbZLuCtFXqnSsvlU8JrXqvhBk/aPDue/cpx7O0HtEBfPpkmSEZg6ulA1dXqBq+yis4vkyh6+YCFZk+LbKDVCsYXoxPVVMxTTyvnPb2QI8y9nwZdQdoP6HfB6EXb9R5LMYl7qTtNRpae+x8jsVvKsQsp7UUtTbIM/icYOCkWOxxH5irq1FyS4zDu6oIYyoXMJJWbrTJkFPqNZ7RYRNoP5vRBOrgOII8vLogXNe9twYX1Su91pv2RlTCsJsV8cPGyAP3duSe6i2kS6UfTxMDSQPX+CvKmMO1o7gT84QUVQBzJVmFaSR/Z9VTVEkHzReXslwmRCB9hKfW395vdFqNGmQplBn6b03y2okwYnuTYc9EGrynGBu6cOxzSsw2iRwVa1xCDU4ctPRWVmNjhZmniHDlX/jXclA1p4UHlG4fLQNkhoY0hH0M5jdA6/Bu4K8NOoNih6WeN5RTM1YeUFNSrUHCWYpznWcLJ9+MYVg/br2gdTqaKbQ4BkyPy1JiTA6EW7oDsdh2hpNllsc9pDmtIJEbHa6V4XNcQ7lzm7eIgn58r5ztAJAiYJ2ueSgqq1XOFgA4yCdrDv6/RKMVQva8bnqeyNxNeRa24+d/5VFJ4DTLST9fkgXkOtG4XznOB7osPZuGmfO3yX3uhvwgHDJ3Unt2C8ZJP9hXe76oPWUw8xFoi2/mQneCwNvE0KnJcMdyPKU7QVloFgoF3mpPcqSf7KAGhQJNlt/Z3AiBISnKcM0wVrsupgBAwo5YCoV8nHRNcIFdUagzJyUdFF2QrTMaiWtCDC1sncFUctf0W4qsEr5lAdEGEdhnjhQ8Q4K3jsE0oerlrTwEGLdiy0EkwBc7/skdbLw9w94NZedeppmCJcQ6RA2iN+o4J/tTmbA8spPDdBu7gungg8XPmFTQwYY2m8ONSblgOqAHSJF7WkgySI6oPsTgYcS2CTq1g/G+Y/yEkwDc7AAaUjzHAlrQbHVAnaTBNxJ6HnotM/AUvfNqtafFcmbC2xPUSGg7mL7qjNmCJDdTSQJBkNIvtcHiRxA6oOd19UkOseQ6QduRCrpvcDefI/VaXN6NFzgGkPN2kjwyN7Aji41T02SbHYUNf4SfECbwebwRuO4/6AUxPREHxCyHp0XHgyJBkci9x802yZrXhzel+hiYQLqdMo7CYY7kWTVuAaFI0AEEMPUDBA2VoxSHNFRNJBea4UDUCFcwqsgoNFk7XQFr8uMQkOCZBT7AINFhXWV7nobD7K8BBbSKvCrZTVjmmEA1RTaVU/dTCCxZj2pzpwcMNRvUcDrdP+22P/10Ref562iCwGahFgIOkdT0MbLnFEVQ2pUdUH+UEkGS5wOoEx1J4M7oBqZ944AQGag3VEg3gmxmQDxO61uLw/vm6g6dN40wBBZTa2xjab2O3VY/KK7NB0k6hdzS3bxOsXDfztGyb5djGjZxsQCAZMC9o+IW68DqgPwuPNKk91JoLmx8QEtm7oY6WkaZiQdieyqwWvSaYgMsSQ2IBaASYFje8WNui+axoJeYDDHidPAIGo6uNJHbYIuhiRBLSQ1wAi4Dr3FhsCdkCbPcuoBlOoHPY4PALhYNbBhzv/LV06FI67XUQ6ixzKjXObXY+JeHNkw1xgtNocBvK0mef7cFxAJYCDaYJsQLR4nWMx2SbEDQPCLTds7RNxa5sEGfoVvd0ntBsXt1NNw5omA0jfcyD1EdivZ6A+SR4ha/fzt6qrH4fSXSASTxIAMC/Q8/MoaiIvJkfS6DaBoQ2Kw5OxUcsxHvGA8jdEOeUC51IhVumUzJCoewdEC9zlBFvYFWWoNjh2p5gWJTRCeZcEDSmLK5ipcYU6SA6k5WPfZUU3KdV4hAG50uSz2hzP3bCxjiKhAuBOkE73t/eEwqVA1rnEgAAmTsIC57QruJLzBsSZ5cXgyQCRKD0YV2oue/VqljwSZaDN3fqFuFHEtBAE6G2uBsSBwYaTY37L7FYrSZMgXJsPygt+EHaRxwD1S/EY8ua/RpB1RP5BLmyQSPDwL/AKkGbxZLahDQ4GYJn4rAGR1MF3rHCdYagdTXGQSADaQJv/Qrczw1M+7efCYb/wDMNJa4hpvJIFvXZVuxzwA0SQAI1nUYt8vRAXVxcUwDLZnvcXBFrbGR29FdVpe5LGNiqDDjo28W4Bv3+qGwBD7PuONrXm3TdaXB0mAtPI2N7REIEtTDtf4XAhoMu6ja0ehHqFXXYwPe3VDWNOlzpIdEgAWkE2gk25WoxODpPJc5suJkm8k9T1SjNcma8HS4iY6ESOxGyDC5u6XlxPxE3NyTAuNrb36/NCtFkXnWXPpuGoS28EWA5iItdDNQX5fifdv7Gx+60RE3WWcnmU1yaflZAXVgWVDl5rk32VdWpKDwtXnulGV8an9/pQbGhUWgyoys5RIWhylyBw9llUypCufUsgnVAgObWVdTFQg211CtUQU59WD8PVbBdLTYGDIuI9QPNYcY0T8JJ3F4B6mwtcOMeS2cB0id7f8ASwWY0Cyo5nhAZ0/NMXjvvHmgsxlZouSWnSCTZwIGraOIIF7eioruLTrp1GzpIlpggGxkz0MbXEId4LnFrxAFoEnhoM99oHlvdX06rwQ0gOAgeNsiJadIJg9fSboFIc51SRYgaQ3gxwOOUWa8i7Y/b0VYcC9zWkOb8WqIu5oE3G4sPRXYOiYc1zthIEEy6ZMAAkEg7kRtdBDDYnQ4X36StVhMUsdh5Ov3g0w0lsDUXOhsDfaJPr5JrlOM1sHBFvT+wg11LEKbnSlGHrJjRqIA8ywQe0g3BWCxmBdSeWnbg9QuoObKSZ3lge09eEGDIT7JqcUvOSlD6B16OZhOqktAA8kEMQYsq+EPiS4myGdWeOCgPEr4hLvxTui8/HFBvqBCd5dXAWepjojaMhBpquMkIJ1dLjVIUW10DQVgFRVrygzVUmmUEm1SFk88qh1dz4DrRubEWmxvH976ioQASTED9lhMYSPgEnfff9RIO8355QEYesNmi0jUSSRMG9hIsdrm3kFTjMYS7Ufhc4mATA5FjfYx3heUmuaHEfAWtLhIk3naxiTx5Fe++BaXNBuSCdu0BvJm89xZB5o2G8iBA8uYg7tPf1VpqNba0zG94A6GY36cdrj0jcgE2Jm0bT08uUPjSDBcGk8C09ROnz/YbIK69YXvYm9zBugqGPeKgeNgY6SP7/Csh2kudIG3Xv6Hn1QjouBPO94PCDdYDENe0ObeQmmHqLCZDjfdu0k2d8mk/ey2NCpKB5QqL6q2UDRqowVEGfzLANDxUi4lCV4IK0mMp6gstjG6SQUA7HjooOA5XrQFCoEEHsCBq0xKMcLIZ+6DZ0rIxj0JRIVzXoCC4qJKiHrxz0F1Jqs1KkPsvffBBKq6WuBE2dbrboSB+yxtYDwyRqNmwDO0k+lytFm1QFkESDbc9DGw6xv/AMpS6gCRe94O8HcQNzaDIB3QB0XgtAIMkapi1rT5ySqcRhw5gJkBrnSeNQvIBNoHPlPdiKBdRJYW3NnnUC0X3G+wNwOD1svq0D7ym0kahE73OqD2vfeLDhBHDv8ADchxdc6bGQCAfO4/5Qb8UP8AI0fF3EbEWF+O/flMsVShsGWi8gHn5dhsPrJKmoARE6TA4+Yt579PQIPLQZ5m4NuYhC1nX/KLnYj6X22/5XzvCIF7T0nmyg1xgkjnfbjn+8IJspyQ2YnvbaRMb8LX5fVIa0ON4CyF2wRud+4PbgR809xGLgA8oNLSqIynWWey7HBw7prTqIGWuQk2bYaRP98kwpVVDEtnyQZivTIQ+pMcYIkFKXNug9rVkL7xWVhZCoNw56kyoqKNFxBIBIBAkd5P8KxlB43aY3246+VjdA1yymCSS5lmlwBmJkATYzG8X2804ZTc40w97XNeACCXeIi5cLWIDh8uiQUtTDqggt7bcXnzAg9UbVxzy0CGCx+EeIAx/wDUERtwgGxbdJgODrbtmPqBdCg9USAbeF1yIsbyDEfJR9y430u+R2QIs2xWhwdvEDT33FufJFYPB6yHhoHxSYkCbWG089voqH0i+uN27EWiQPzf0fpWjw7Q0ACw4QDU8vaOXfOOnTyHyQWYZXqOoRIEfCBxG42lPwVRWegxGPpv1OboiG25aTbpfiUoLyGkvI1aoFhYff0sIW0zWHA+RWNxFER8N+TFv+DsgHq3Mx1++3kqgCTOo3/aIPnyP7Csqt+cR91AumwIAjvHM7fwg+dVm8m3z6IgVS6EM2nsZ4PpF/2RuV4N9R0AGAbkoGODoFjZ/Mb+nRPcC4kT+6twuCaN7lEGAggTCmavCqqOCq96EAmZMskryn2JdOyR1hdBRUVBar33VJQa2hiajbNcQJntNuPRF4bF1TDA83sOO2/Czbcwd0b9fuimZi4HZvyP3QajTVcNJcSIuJFr8gcyAovNYeEW5tpnYAeZtY7rPNzN1/C36/dTOaviIbv0P3QPalXEsBEn807Hzm3RAYjM6jWnxQACB4RYHja4mLdktdmr5JhvPB535QmY5g5zHSG8Hngg9UFH/rTvfOe4z+UHsD2/sQnmEz1jvzQsHUrGBYbKptczwg6g3MWkbhU1sxHVc4di3jZxXjsfU/Ug2eKx7eoWexlUONjab2niQNxaQfLvsk7sS47lWYSsQTt63QGVduv7Xtx5qgN2DZJPESV9QfJFgATsJt5SVosE4MHhY3zMk/OUFeUZI4w6pYfp+/RaOlSbTEAADtZKH5m+dm/I/dDVszfPH1+6B+/FIepjFnzmL+31+6pfjndvr90DypjJVL8ZCRnGO7KQxB6D6oGzcWhazryhPxR6D6/deVcSeg+v3QEF6rKC/EHsvffnsg//2Q==";
                     base64Data  =   binaryData.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ""); 
                     binaryData  =   new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64').toString('binary');
                     console.log(binaryData) 

fs.writeFile("out1.jpg", binaryData, "binary", function (err) {//working
                        if(err)
                        console.log("ERROR : "+err); // writes out file without error, but it's not a valid image
                    }); 
                     fs.writeFile("out2.jpg", body, "binary", function (err) { //not working
                        if(err)
                        console.log("ERROR : "+err); // writes out file without error, but it's not a valid image
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
fs.writeFile(path1, body, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err){
                  });
```

With

```
fs.writeFile(path1, 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + new Buffer(body).toString('base64'), {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err){
                  });
```

Comment: helped for the hard coded image base64 but still the URL image file is not opening

Answer (score 1):

This is a deprecation warning (I don't think it's an error yet, but it will be soon).

You just need to change the way you call `Buffer`. Instead of instantiating it directly use the static `from` method.

```
new Buffer(body)  // Old
Buffer.from(body) // New
```

Comment: I think you misread the question  , I've made some edits in the OP.