# How can i store following image using nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm **scraping** the data from the website in order to **scrape** further data i need to solve captcha that i'm thinking of giving user to solve but site uses language PHP after some digging site is using PHP-GD that i need to scrap as image but URL giving me some values that i don't know how to procede

```
URL something like : <img src="www.some.urk/captcha.php" />
```

in img tag i followed the URL than i don't understand the data how to construct an image from that data

here is the data i revive from the URL

HEADER:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=8o58tnqgupo4h5si8499nij5m6
```

BODY:

```
����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality =
   80
       ��C
       
       
            
       %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(��C
       
       
       
       (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((��A"��    
       ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�  
       %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� 
       ���w!1AQaq"2�B����   #3R�br�
       $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?�R���߈uO
       _�}��}���{qp��I��؂cldo\0�����>���6��,���ūMeu�'6��i��(مb
       0b����p�详���d�֗}���=���Mn����Q��q�   �vʀU1gx��%����
       ����+K�5.5�4�b�G��]�[a���@�3�1����x%캶���쩧�z}�����m�j��Y�d,Ĵ�����U������
       ����r�h�:T-m7���R;������FA����8P�h��S�:���^<Os��Ki+DIFxܩ*H����([�~!�<5%�u�K,/m*�k,sD�
       ��*�����z�V��뺴�\�7�O�VM�vP�i��Z4�UU�rX�O��x��> �=���/b{ct����6�-ÀiH��
   csd�y��]s����*�O��?:����S��Q�w�ؼ�UD�m7�r��R����?�����o���z���&�������V�7ofw���4?�>'���4�3S�m��ﲻ[�$֞r�ȕ����c/$����(��(��(���
```

here tried but not the expected result you can see here
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60939713/problem-in-saving-the-image-saving-from-url-in-nodejs)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching some library i find the following solution with JIMP library

```
function hello (){ 

    request(url, function(error, response, html){ 

        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
             var img = $('img.control-label');
             var img_url = $('img.control-label').attr('src')
             console.log(img);
             console.log(url+img_url);
             console.log(response.headers);

                     Jimp.read({
                        url: url+img_url, // Required!
                        headers: {Cookie: response.headers}, 
                      })
                        .then(image => {
                          // Do stuff with the image.'
                          console.log("successes : "+image); 
                          image.write("path.png"); 
                        })
                        .catch(err => { 
                          console.log(err); 
                        });
        }
    })
}
hello();
```